# What verb is being dropped in 「また、近いうちに」

Tags: verbs, copula

Consider

> また、近いうちに。
>
> Let's meet again soon.

I'm assuming a verb is being implicitly dropped here. Which one is it? Is it the volitional copula (だろう)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

また近いうちにだろう would only make sense as a response to a question like 'When do you expect [something] to happen again?'

I'd imagine it's just something like 「また近いうちに（お会いしましょう）」